# How to use one single class multiple times on a TabBarView?

Tags: dart, flutter

I want make a TabBarView using only one class, but using it multiple times only changing the parameters I pass to the constructor of the class.

When I tried doing, it works only for the first line it is called, and all the other pages are exactly the same as the first, like every line executed the first one.

```
body: new TabBarView(
                controller: controller,
                children: <Widget>[
                    Lan.OnuPort('SEFI', '0'),
                    Lan.OnuPort('SEFI', '1'),
                    Lan.OnuPort('SEFI', '2'),
                ],
            ),
```

When I run the app all 3 pages show what have to be only on the `Lan.OnuPort('SEFI', '0'),` like I've runned that line 3 times

EDIT:
The Lan.OnuPort class is only a Statefull Widget that contains a ListView

```
class OnuPort extends StatefulWidget {
    final String pop;
    final String port;
    OnuPort(this.pop, this.port);

    OnuPortState createState() => new OnuPortState(this.pop, this.port);
}

class OnuPortState extends State<OnuPort> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<OnuPort>{
    final String pop;
    final String port;
    OnuPortState(this.pop, this.port);

    bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
```

Comment: Show code for `Lan.OnuPort`.
Also try to put a different key for eacy `Lan.OnuPort` and see if it works.

Comment: But, how can I put these different keys?

Comment: Please read this article: https://medium.com/flutter-io/keys-what-are-they-good-for-13cb51742e7d

Comment: I've used the Keys and it worked perfectly!!! Thanks a lot!